# Нужна ли запятая , там где скобки перед "куда"

Tags: пунктуация

— Они погрузили свои пожитки на машины и разъехались кто куда, — заключил А.

— Вопрос только(,) куда? По лагерям? По загородным домам? Куда, по-твоему, местным податься?

Проблемная запятая в скобках. Если это уточнение, то должна быть, но ведь одиночные вопросительные слова не обособляются в конце предложения. Но хочется поставить.
В НКРЯ нашла все четыре варианта: без знаков, запятая, двоеточие и тире. Логика у всех разная.

Answer (score 2):

Из Розенталя ( http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=260#ppp_4 ; § 33, п. 4, 3)) известно, что запятой **не** отделяются *неполные придаточные* предложения, состоящие *из одного союзного слова* (относительного местоимения или наречия):
*Он ушёл и не сказал **куда**; Трудно сказать **почему**.*

Наш случай близок ко *второму* примеру, где главное предложение в СПП - безличное (ср. "вопрос почему - неизвестно почему - трудно сказать почему"). Это подтверждается и поиском по книгам (google books): в результатах на запрос "*вопрос-только-куда*" либо просто отсутствует запятая (зачастую так выглядит законченное предложение, напр.: А. Адамов, "Со многими неизвестными", Воен. изд-во СП "Панас", 1992), либо ставится *двоеточие* (буквальная трактовка слова "вопрос"); реже ставится интонационное *тире*. Поскольку в нашем случае в конце стоит *вопросительный знак*, после слов "вопрос только" логично было бы поставить **двоеточие**.

Comment: *...После слова "вопрос" логично было бы поставить двоеточие.* — после слова **только**, наверное.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уточню.